# Can image of any size and dimension be used as an icon in JFrame?

Tags: java, icons, jframe

I am trying to set the icon that appears in the top-left corner of a frame as a custom image with .gif extension, instead of the default java icon. I tried using :

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/jlab/mainframe/images/jLab.gif"));
```

However, whenever I run the application, the default java icon still appears. Can image of any size be used as an icon? if yes then kindly resolve my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (it will look in the classpath):

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("/jlab/mainframe/images/jLab.gif")));
```

Comment: Kudos!..it worked..can you explain the difference between your answer and my approach?

Comment: Well you were not specifying the full path to your image, so the program couldn't find it. You had to tell him to look directly in your project (as your path is relative to your project), where it is available as a resource.